# Changing messages on Slack

Tags: slack-api

So I'm attempting to change a message in slack through my slackbot at the end of a chain of events. I'm able to change it for the first few instances, but I'm not able to do the very last one. I'm 99% sure that it is because I have reached the 5 interactions limit since I am indeed going through 5 interactions with the user prior to my final message. If this is the case, is there a way to change a message without server responses? I ask because the last message is simply a thank you message to the user for participating. It doesn't actually require any input from data on the server to accomplish. I feel like I read about doing it somewhere, but for the life of me I cannot find it again. Any help or links would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** The user is interacting with buttons through interactive messages to respond to some questions. The current method of updating messages are with chat.update and setting "response_type": "ephemeral" within the json params that I am sending.

Comment: Please specify: How are you updating the messages currently? How is the user communicating with your bot? (slash command, Interactive messages, bot mention, ...)

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I have updated. I believe that those are the specifics you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative method to using `chat.update` is to simply reply with the message to the request from Slack. This will replace the existing message by default. It has no limit that I am aware of, so it solves your problem.

This works great with slash commands and interactive messages.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_a_command) for more details.

Comment: For clarity, would this be to the response_url field that I am to send the response to? I'm only seeing a reference to it at the top of that tutorial/api. P.S. You're awesome, you've answered quite a few of my questions (dumb or not). I thank you for that.

Comment: Thanks :) yes, you can do that. or if you respond within 3 seconds, you can just respond directly to the Slack request. Just set header to JSON and output the message. (at least that is how it works in PHP)

Comment: That definitely got me a lot closer to what I am wanting. With the ephemeral messages. It solved the exact issue I was asking you about, actually. I do have a couple more questions. First, I know to use the "style" parameter to make buttons red or green if I want, but can I use any custom colors? I tried using a "color" parameter but as expected, it only changed the bars on the left. Secondly, can my ephemeral messages fully replace the old message (but only for the interacting user)? I can only send new messages to users that are only visible to them.